# Different notations of Taylor expansion

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, notation, taylor-expansion

I have two Taylor series expansions of cosine:

$$\cos(x) = 1 - \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^4}{24} + w_2(x)x^5$$

and

$$\cos(x) = 1 - \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^4}{24} + o(x^5)$$

Can you explain me the difference between these two notations? I do understand that the second one is small $o$ notation, but I never saw the upper one with $w$. What is the difference?

Comment: If the first expansion has the condition "for some function $w_2 \in o(1)$" or "for some function $w_2$ such that $\lim_{x \to 0} w_2(x) =0$" then the two are identical.

Comment: There is the condition "for all functions $w_j$ where $w_j(0) = \lim_{x \to 0} w_j(x) = 0$. Not sure if this is the correct translation to english, but hopefully you can get the idea.

Comment: I will correct it, thank you, my mistake.